# Why changes on attributes at a numpy subclass does not change the subclass array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, attributes, subclass

I'm having the following problem when I subclass a numpy array

for example:

```
import numpy

class Example(numpy.ndarray):
   def __new__(cls, x, y):
       dt = [('x', 'float'), ('y', 'float')]
       buffer = numpy.array(zip(x, y),dtype=dt)
       obj = super(Example, cls).__new__(cls, buffer.shape, dtype=dt,
                                          buffer=buffer)
       obj.x = numpy.array(x, dtype='float')
       obj.y = numpy.array(y, dtype='float')
       return obj

   def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.x = getattr(obj, 'x', None)
        self.y = getattr(obj, 'y', None)
```

If I do operations with obj.x and obj['x'], one does not change the other. For example these operations will show different results

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,1,1,1]

obj = Example(x,y)
obj.x = obj.x / 2.
print obj.x, obj['x']
```

or

```
obj = Example(x,y)
obj['x'] = obj['x'] / 2.
print obj.x, obj['x']
```

How can I make that whenever I do an operation with one of them (obj.x or obj['x']), the other also changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[('x', 'float'), ('y', 'float')]` as the datatype tells numpy to create a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html) with fields named `x` and `y`.
Those are accessed using brackets, as you've shown.
Now you've also added attributes (accessed using `obj.<name>`) to your class.
However, you've created new arrays for the attributes.
To fix the attribute notation you need to have the `x` and `y` attributes point to the array fields by those names, rather than separate arrays.
So change

```
   obj.x = numpy.array(x, dtype='float')
   obj.y = numpy.array(y, dtype='float')
```

to

```
   obj.x = obj['x']
   obj.y = obj['y']
```

**edit** this fixes only the second test case in the question.  Assigning to `x` or `y` still assigns a new object as the attribute, rather than updating `x` or `y`.
To fix this it would be necessary to modify the `__setattr__` method of the class (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access))

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if attr in ['x', 'y']:
         getattr(self, attr)[:] = attr
    else:
         setattr(self, attr, value)
```

However, Numpy already has an array type to allow accessing fields as attributes.
You can use it like this

```
obj = np.array(np.r_[x, y], dtype=[('x', 'float'), ('y', 'float')]) 
obj = obj.view(np.recarray)
```

So congratulations! You've effectively re-implemented [record arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html)(well, `np.recarray` won't allow accessing fields names matching attributes or functions `ndarray` has.  So names like `mean` or `ndim` are out, while your code would allow these).
It's always a good (and very frustrating) sign when you spend hours creating something numpy already has.

Comment: Hi @user2699, thanks! The solution obj.x = obj['x'] will solve for 
    obj['x'] = obj['x'] / 2.
    print obj.x, obj['x']
but not for:
    obj.x = obj.x / 2.
    print obj.x, obj['x']

I am aware of the existence of the record array. In the example I simplified the class to simplify the question, but there is many other methods and attributes that I am trying to add.  If I put obj = obj.view(np.recarray), my class type will be a recarray, and it gives me an error if I try to apply the extended methods. Now I am thinking if should I just subclass the recarray, instead of the ndarray?

Comment: @bennu, thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the answer to show how you can fix that.  I'd expect it to be easier to subclass `recarray`, but I don't know.

Comment: Hi @user2699, I just sub-classed the record array actually, I thought that might be simpler. But very nice to see your solution, I might need this in some other time!